# How to find the magnetization of a neodymium magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I am interested in knowing how to find the value for Magnetisation of cylindrical N35 neodymium magnets based on the information sheet, or through the means of an experiment.  This is to calculate its magnetic field, with the assumption of uniform magnetisation.

How would I go about this?

On the information sheet I am provided with the information shown below:

| Material Type | Residual Flux Density (Br) | Coercive Force (Hc) | Intrinsic Coercive Force (Hci) | Max. Energy Product (BH) max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N35 | 11.7–12.1 KGs | > 11.0 KOe | > 12 KOe | 33–35 MGOe |

The formula I am using is shown, is taken from:
https://web.pa.msu.edu/people/stump/EM/chap9/9ex1.pdf

$$
\mathbf B(0,0,z) = 
  \frac{\mu_0M_0}2 
  \left\lbrace 
    \frac{z+\ell/2}{\sqrt{a^2+(z+\ell/2)^2}}
    -\frac{z-\ell/2}{\sqrt{a^2+(z-\ell/2)^2}}
  \right\rbrace \hat{\mathbf k} 
$$

Surface field and pull force are also known.

Answer (score 0):

The equation that you have here is similar to what is shown in the [Surface Fields 101](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=surface-fields-101) blog post from K&J Magnetics. I think that the visual that they have in the post and the explanation of the math might make it a little easier to understand the equation that you have shown here. Also since you have a range of Residual flux density there could be a range to the answer unless you assume that all of the material has the same residual flux density pinned to a specific value.